# In Abaqus, how can I calculate stress and strain from displacement time history which was got from external program?

Tags: fortran, abaqus, post-processing

I am developing a analysis procedure using `Abaqus&Fortran` as follows:

1. Generate FEM model using Abaqus, and do an modal analysis in `Abaqus`.Thus, an    DAT results were generated.
2. With `Fortran`, read the DAT file to get the FEM model and modal results, and then calculate the displacement history for each node, using my own algorithm.
3. **Finally purpose(but I don't know how to do it yet): GET the strain/stress time history of each node, or several chosen nodes.**

The displacement history (in `step 2`) can be written into a bin file. Can I use python to read it and call Abaqus to calculate stress or strain, and then write them into Odb database? Which type of analysis step should I use? 
Or, can it just be done in a post-processing procedure, how to do it?

Is anyone has similar experience and could give me some advice on this issue?

Thanks a lot!